# ImportXML and a hidden class

Tags: xpath, google-sheets

I've been playing with ImortXML to see if we can pull product catalogues from page instead of using scripts.

```
<textarea id="product-static-data" class="hidden">
    {
                "id": "337501AB6",
                "productId": "337501AB6",
                "name": "flat sheet 180 threadcount",                       
                "price": "R 157.00 - R 217.00",
                "brandURL": "/plp/home/_/N-1z14108",

            </textarea>
```

First possible issue is that the class is hidden, will ImportXML be able to parse it?

If it can I need to pull the first value of the "price" field, and I am really pulling my hair out.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this function exactly:

```
=regexextract(substitute(IMPORTXML("ADD YOUR URL HERE","//*[@id='product-static-data']"),"""","'"),"'price': '(R \d+\.\d+).*")
```

Comment: Works perfectly. Thanks!